# RESTful API 2x nodejs apps on same server, with fallback

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, docker, horizontal-scaling

**Micro Services** I would like to have `front-end-web` and `back-end-api` nodejs applications running. Communicating via RESTful HTTP APIs, on a single machine (read ec2).

**Stateless** I would like to scale these horizontally across ec2 instances in the future. Using `Redis` (ElasiCache) and `MySQL` (RDS)  (read stateless)

**Load Balanced** When scaled i would load balance with an ELB. no problme there.

**QUESTION:**  If a `back-end-api` goes down on a machine, is it possible to somehow fallback to another ec2 server running an `back-end-api` instance? How would i do this.

**Why not seperate the API app?** well i would like to keep them on the same server for latency and maintainability.

oh btw i use docker :-)